# increase expiration time of item in Cache

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I have code to add item to cache:

```
public static void AddTask(string name, string value,int seconds)
{
   _onCacheRemove = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved);
   HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(name, value, null,
                        DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                        CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, _onCacheRemove);
}
```

For example, `seconds`  equals 120.  After 20 seconds I want to set expiration time again 120 seconds. How can I do this?

PS. A can't delete this item and add again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the item to the cache - you can provide a callback that is to be invoked when the runtime is about to remove the item from the cache - rather than your current one which gets called when it's already been removed.

In that callback, you can cancel the remove process and extend the entry's lifetime.

See [this overload of insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491414.aspx) and this documentation about the [CacheItemUpdateCallback delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitemupdatecallback.aspx)

Although you're already handling the removed event - this 'updated' event is basically the same thing - it just gives you the ability to cancel the expiration if need be.

Comment: I need to increase before invoked callback.

Comment: I don't see why you should - in your CacheItemUpdateCallback delegate you either extend the lifetime of the object in the cache, or you allow it to expire, using the event as a replacement for your current CacheItemRemoveCallback handler